# How to display the highest amount in PL/SQL along with ($) symbol?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Below is my current code in which I have to display on two populated tables called department and employee.

```
Employee Name:    Johnshon
Job:              Service Writer
Total Pay:        $56,000
========================================
Department Name:  Service
Highest Total Pay: $4,500.00
```

I am having problems getting the highest total pay to get displayed.  I think my problem may be where I declared another variable name v_dpay.  I'm not sure if I need that or not.  I am pretty sure I should use MAX to get the highest total paid in the department.  I am also having some problems implementing the ($) and (,) in my output to two decimal places.

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Please enter the Employee ID:'

DECLARE
v_eid     employee.employee_id%TYPE := &p_1;
v_count   NUMBER;
v_name    employee.employee_name%TYPE;
v_job     employee.job%TYPE;
v_pay     employee.salary%TYPE;
v_did     department.department_id%TYPE;
v_dname   department.department_name%TYPE;
v_dpay    ?????????????????????????????????
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO     v_count
    FROM     employee
WHERE employee_id = v_eid;

IF v_count = 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_eid || ' is not in the employee table.');
ELSE
    select employee_name, job, salary + NVL(commission, 0), department_id
    into v_name, v_job, v_pay, v_did
    from employee
    where employee_id = v_eid;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name: ' || v_name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job: ' || v_job);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Pay: ' || v_pay);

if v_did is not null then
  select department_name, MAX(v_dpay)
  into v_dname, v_dpay
  from department, employee
  where department_id = v_did;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department Name: ' || v_dname);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Highest Total Pay: ' || v_dpay);
 else
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('N/A');
  end if;
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Max(v_dpay)? Why take the maximum of an undeclared variable into the same variable?

Comment: Yea I realized after about 2 hours it should have been MAX(salary). Opps

Answer (score 1):

Taking the maximum value of `v_dpay` is just going to give you...the value of `v_dpay`.  I suspect this is not what you wanted.  Perhaps the following might help:

```
SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, MAX(e.SALARY + NVL(e.COMMISSION, 0))
  INTO v_dname, v_dpay
  FROM DEPARTMENT d
  INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e
    ON (e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID)
  WHERE d.DEPARTMENT_ID = v_did;
```

Based on the posted code this SELECT should get you what you're looking for - and if it doesn't a little tweaking ought to do it.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: thank you, but after working with this code I keep getting the error:  " not a single-group function"

Comment: Hmmm...try adding `GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID` and see if that improves things for you.

Comment: He's selecting Max() of a variable name into the same variable name, so I think there are other issues here.

Answer (score 1):

Bob's covered where you're going wrong with the `max` calculation; the `v_dpay` variable cold be declared as `employee.salary%TYPE` to maych `v_pay`, or as `NUMBER`, or another numeric data type. You could re-use `v_pay` but it's clearer if it has its own variable I think.

For the display, you need the [`TO_CHAR(number)` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions201.htm):

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Highest Total Pay: ' || TO_CHAR(v_dpay, 'C999G999G999D99'));
```

The [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34570) uses `C` to represent the currency, which will give you `$` if your NLS settings are for the US (or other countries that use that symbol!); `G` for the group separator which will give you `,` and `D` for the decimal separator which will give you `.`, again based on your NLS settings.

A less portable equivalent would be `'$999,999,999.99'`, but using the generic versions isn't a bad habit to get into.

Comment: I am continuing to get this error at run time: " not a single-group function"